# Where is the Toolbar in OS X Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, toolbar

since the Lion update, every toolbar is missing.

For example:

- Word 2011
- Adium
- Finder

In Snow Leopard it was possible to click on an little button in right up corner. But it's not visible anymore.

In Word 2011, I can make it visible with the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcurt. But the Button is already missing in every program.

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot? Are you missing a certain functionality?

Comment: The Pill Button is gone -> On peurpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mac OS X Lion, the toolbar can be hidden and shown from the View menu.
[image: View Menu]

You can also right-click the title bar of a window to find a "Hide Toolbar" option, if you'd prefer to do it with the mouse.
[image: Title Bar Contextual Menu]

Comment: is there no button anymore?

Comment: Nope, the toolbar pill button was probably user-tested to show that most people never noticed it, and so it has been replaced with the fullscreen button on apps that support it.